# Wireless Covering a Two Story + Basement House?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have the following setup for my house:

- Cable modem (upstairs)
- Ethernet upstairs / main floor / basement
- Bunch of old routers
- OnHub

I'm trying to figure out what the right layout here is. I was thinking of putting the OnHub on the main floor, so that it's central (can reach basement and upstairs), but then the cable modem is upstairs, which means I need some switch upstairs (old router). I can do DDWRT on the old router, and try to bridge them with the OnHub, but I feel like I'm doing something unnecessarily complicated.

Alternative #2, put the OnHub upstairs next to the cable modem - but then does it reach the basement? And then do I need to have a second router for the basement as an extender?

Answer (score 1):

- For Wi-Fi, "Does it reach" can be only answered by yourself, experimentally. (For example, I work at a place where the signal can easily reach through two floors, but the *walls* are completely impenetrable...)
- If you need a switch, then... buy a switch? They're cheap. You don't need a whole combo router/switch/Wi-Fi "wireless router" that costs 10 times as much, if all you need is more Ethernet ports and aren't going to use the routing functions.

  Even if you already have a bunch of old routers, I'd still say use a switch where you need one. Or at least configure those routers in bridge mode (as below).
- Similarly, if you need more Wi-Fi APs, you can actually get standalone APs, without a router function. (I think some stores call them "Wi-Fi extenders"?)
- Whatever layout you choose, try to avoid stacking routers – leave routing enabled in the "main" router, but switch all others to "bridge" mode (e.g. see [OnHub's docs on that](https://support.google.com/onhub/answer/6240987?hl=en)). This avoids [double NAT](https://support.google.com/onhub/answer/6277579?hl=en).

  If they do not have an option to switch from routing/NAT to bridging, then just turn off DHCP and connect everything to LAN ports instead of WAN.

Comment: This is great advice - one of the problems I neglected to mention was that my cable modem requires connecting to a router (it needs an associated MAC address). So a switch next to the modem won't do...

Comment: It "needs an associated MAC address"? As in... it's just a modem without any routing functions and requires an actual router in front of it? (In that case, sure, put a router in front of it.) Or does it do something weirder, like checking LAN clients' MACs? _(Never used cable modems, it's all ADSL here.)_

Comment: Yep, it locks to a MAC address, but does not check all client's MACs - you have to hard reset it when you switch routers.